# Python sum items in sequence

Tags: python

From a starting list of coordinates (xCoord variable) I would like to apply an offset to those values (Offset_X variable). Offset_X is a list with sublists whose length will be equal to xCoord.

It is important to highlight that the first item of xCoord variable (xCoord[0]) will sum the first item of the first sublist within Offset_X list and then, that result will sum the second item in the first sublist.

Please find a screenshot with the inputs and the final result that I am behind (new_xCoord variable):

```
xCoord = [2,5]
Offset_X = [[3,4,6],[1,5,3,4]]
```

```
new_xCoord = [[5,9,15],[6,11,14,18]]  # <- result
```

Thank you,

Comment: Please provide the code directly in the question and not as an external link.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to take the [tour] and get some tips on [ask]. To start, add your code as text, not as an image. Include a sample of input and output. Also, show what you have tried so far, and what specifically is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more efficient ways of doing it, but this works...

```
xCoord = [2,5]
Offset_X = [[3,4,6],[1,5,3,4]]

def calc(xCoord, Offset_X):
    new_xCoord = []      # create new coords list
    for cor, offs in zip(xCoord, Offset_X):  # iterate the coords and offset
        inter = cor 
        arr = []          # create empty list
        for off in offs:  # iterate the current coordinates offset list
            inter += off           # increase value by the offset
            arr.append(inter)      # append it to the list
        new_xCoords.append(arr)    # append the list to new coords list
    return new_xCoords             # return the new coords list

print(calc(xCoord, Offset_X))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[5, 9, 15], [6, 11, 14, 18]]
```

---

Update

The following example likely performs better since using the `itertools` module typically offers more efficient solutions.

```
import itertools

xCoord = [2,5]
Offset_X = [[3,4,6],[1,5,3,4]]

def calc(xCoord, Offset_X):
    new_xCoord = []
    for cor, offs in zip(xCoord, Offset_X):
        offs[0] += cor
        new_xCoord.append(list(itertools.accumulate(offs)))
    return new_xCoords

print(calc(xCoord, Offset_X))
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a helper function makes this solvable as a list comprehension so you don't have to append to lists. Accumulate keeps the running total for each element in the arrays and yield a one total at a time.

```
def accumulate(x, offsets):
    new_x = x
    for offset in offsets:
        new_x += offset
        yield(new_x)
    
new_xCoord = [list(accumulate(x, offsets))for x, offsets in zip(xCoord, Offset_X)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in module `itertools` for that, it has the function [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) that may be handy for this.

```
from itertools import accumulate
print([list(accumulate(o, initial=x))[1:] for x, o in zip(xCoord, Offset_X)])
```